# Direct Mapped Cache, Filling out Contents of Main Memory

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture

I am preparing for an exam in Computer Architecture. I understand how caching works and how data gets copied from Main Memory to the Cache depending on the Address.

However, I am unable to figure out how the contents of a main memory are filled out depending on the address. For instance, in the image linked to below, I can easily fill out the contents of the cache, but I do not understand how I should fill the cells that are pointed at with the arrows.

My Professor did not really talk much about that part and I can't complete the actual problem without further help. Please help me understand how I should fill the contents of the Main Memory!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways you can fill out the main memory.

1. When a cache entry is evicted from, it is stored in the main memory.
2. When your program load data to memory, from a file. Lets say you have an image you want to process, you can load this to memory and process it than accessing the data from file every time, which is slower.
3. Direct Memory Access (DMA) operations - These are there to read/write memory without CPU interaction. You may have a DMA operation filling out an input buffer which then CPU processes.
4. You could have multiple programs working together, one producing data and other consuming it. For example, your first program may be doing a matrix multiplication and the second is using that result. So the first program will write out its result to main memory and will pass a reference to the second program to use it.

Comment: In this specific example, if the first memory slot accessed is the one next to FFFFFC address, does the value for the memory data need to be provided? If not, how would I find out what exactly is stored in it?

Comment: Lets say your program requested data at address 0xFFFFF8 and your cache line is two words wide. So that whatever in locations 0xFFFFF8 and 0xFFFFFC will be forwarded to the cache. If your program never wrote to location, 0xFFFFFC what ever the bit values stored in that memory location will be forwarded.